# Error column specified more than once when inserting an entity with EmbeddedId using Micronaut Data

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, micronaut, composite-primary-key, micronaut-data

I'm using **Micronaut Data JDBC** and I'm facing an error. I have this entity:

```
@MappedEntity(value = "document_metadata")
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DocumentMetadataJDBCEntity implements DocumentMetadata {

    @Embeddable
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class MetadataPk {

        @MappedProperty(value = "document_uid")
        @NotNull
        private UUID documentUid;

        @MappedProperty(value = "metadata_key")
        @NotNull
        private String metadataKey;

        public UUID getDocumentUid() {
            return documentUid;
        }

        public String getMetadataKey() {
            return metadataKey;
        }

    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private MetadataPk metadataPk;

    @NotNull
    private String metadataValue;

    public MetadataPk getMetadataPk() {
        return metadataPk;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMetadataKey() {
        return getMetadataPk().getMetadataKey();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMetadataValue() {
        return metadataValue;
    }

    public UUID getDocumentUid() {
        return getMetadataPk().getDocumentUid();
    }

}
```

And when inserting I get this error:

```
io.micronaut.data.exceptions.DataAccessException: SQL error executing INSERT: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "document_metadata" ("metadata_key","metadata_value","document_uid","document_uid","metadata_key") VALUES ('id','1234','c960d8de-99a4-40a6-91bf-b0d4a73910d6'::uuid,'c960d8de-99a4-40a6-91bf-b0d4a73910d6'::uuid,'id') was aborted: ERROR: column "document_uid" specified more than once
```

The code for saving is the next one:

```
Set<DocumentMetadataJDBCEntity> metadataSet = metadata.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new DocumentMetadataJDBCEntity(new DocumentMetadataJDBCEntity.MetadataPk(
                        savedDocument.getUid(), e.getKey()), e.getValue())).collect(toSet());
        Iterable<DocumentMetadataJDBCEntity> persistedMetadata = documentMetadataJDBCRepository.saveAll(metadataSet);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@Transient` to your convenience accessor (getter) methods:

```java
    @Override
    @Transient
    public String getMetadataKey() {
        return getMetadataPk().getMetadataKey();
    }

    @Transient
    public UUID getDocumentUid() {
        return getMetadataPk().getDocumentUid();
    }
```

It "tells" Micronaut not to save the return value into the DB.